# mysql select id from geted id and perform increment operation

Tags: php, mysql

i have page in which i get id from previous page.
now i wants to update table according to that id.but currently i am using two sql queries.i wants to combine both queries and make a single query.
here is my code.

```
$id = $_GET['id'];

//GET DETAILS
$sql = $conn->query("SELECT clicks FROM banners WHERE id = '".$_GET['id']."'")->fetch_object();
$lastClick = $sql->clicks;
$newClick = $lastClick + 1;

$insertt = "UPDATE banners SET clicks='$newClick' WHERE id = ".$_GET['id']."";
$insert = $conn->query($insertt);
if($insert){
    echo "Redirecting to you At.  ".$sql->link;
}else{
    echo $insertt;
}
```

so is it possible to combine two queries.
Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can increment the column value in update query itself.

```
$sql = "UPDATE banners SET clicks = clicks + 1 WHERE id = '".$_GET['id']."'";
```

Also sanitize `$_GET['id']` by escaping it before using its value in the query (assuming you are using `mysqli`)

```
mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['id']);
```

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is quite simple :)

`UPDATE banners SET clicks= clicks+1 WHERE id = ".$_GET['id']."`

But don't use concatenation when you are doing SQL requests. Please use binding instead (to avoid SQL injections) :

```
$sql = $conn->prepare("UPDATE banners SET clicks= clicks+1 WHERE id = :id");
$sql->bindParam(':id', $_GET['id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sql->execute();
```